# SceneKit transform values, how are they implemented?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

[Apple's SceneKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407964-transform?language=objc) suggests that the transform matrix of an object consists of rotation, position, and scale information. However the transform matrix is a 4x4 matrix, the last column being 0,0,0,1. What are these values exactly and is there a more detailed explanation to this matrix? Like which columns/rows represent what, why is there 4 rows and what is the last column for?

Example code:

```
for t in 0...3 {
    print("\t")
    for n in frame.camera.transform[t] {
        print(String(format: "%10.1f", n),terminator: "");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
   0.1      -0.7       0.7       0.0    
   1.0       0.2      -0.1       0.0    
  -0.1       0.7       0.7       0.0    
   0.3      -0.1       0.0       1.0
```

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Other_kinds_of_transformations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is the CATransform3D:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catransform3d

Which is some of the most asinine "documentation" in the history of Apple's notoriously asinine documentation.

Try this, from the wayback machine, when they used to at least talk about things a little more deeply... somewhat: https://web.archive.org/web/20111010140734/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#/web/20111012014313/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html

m34 is the most interesting of the entire matrix, as it's usually referred to as being responsible for [perspective](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH8-SW13).

And here's one of the best articles ever written about Core Animation, that explains some aspects of this transform: http://www.thinkandbuild.it/introduction-to-3d-drawing-in-core-animation-part-1/

Comment: My god, I have been so annoyed by Apple's, "documentation" lately that it made me feel cringe every time I read one. That webarchive version though, that is a full-blown documentation, it is great. I wonder what went so wrong with Apple that they decided to ditch that. New ones have no examples at all, they rather only post whole sample projects which is not helpful at all when I need only one specific case. Thanks. Also +1 for the "asinine" comment :)

Comment: About the time they neglected Core Animation, Apple began turning weird and presumptive with their documentation, and everything they do with regards software development. This worsened when the app store became a thing, and has grown exponentially worse under Tim Cook.

Comment: My guess: Tim Cook considers himself a "real world engineer" and has a DRIVE THEM HARD attitude to Apple software "engineers" because they've failed at expectation management, estimation, communication and self motivation. All known problems of coders. But not things that real world engineers have any means or experience dealing with because they're self motivating and groomed in matters of communication, estimation and expectation management. Even the shoddy ones... or... especially the shoddy ones. Software developers kick back when pushed. They kick back by doing less, of everything.

Comment: That's exactly right. Some time after Jobs died I started to feel an incoherency at Apple. Some of their divisions do a great job, some suck, but the important point is they can't really connect eveything together.

Comment: Take iMac Pro for example. They bragged a lot about how "AR ready" it is and that it is more "performance per buck" to supposedly attract devs. What they don't understand is that like %90 of AI&AR developers/scientists will not want to spend 5000$ on a product no matter how good it is especially **until MacOS and iOS are matured as an AI&AR platform**, which it will not because we will not buy the iMac Pro. Either I am missing something entirely or this shows just how much they have no idea what they are doing

Comment: I meant to point out the lack of communication and clear vision as you suggested btw. Their teams working on ML, AR and VR seem to be making good progress, but bad documentation. Their promotion of this whole process is also confusing because as a developer I have no idea what to do with Apple's VR because 1: there is only one laptop which works decently with VR, and that is the maxed out new mbp, and 2: because of the first item, there is not much resource on Apple's VR because well, not much people use it. They are losing developers and I think that will hit hard eventually

Comment: The iMac Pro is ridiculous: the result of a very bad decision with the Mac Pro Dustbin "design" and Final Cut Pro X. Following these, and an inability to admit mistakes, the iMac Pro is offered as a stopgap, and far too late, offering far too little for far too much money. It's at least $9k to spec an iMac Pro as you'd want it for serious visual and/or audio production and design. Yet none of the benefits of normal workstations (of that price) are inherent to its "design". Attempting to commodify elite workstations doesn't work. And nobody needs a genius IQ to see this. But hubris blinkers.

Comment: Coders are one of a few user types that stand to benefit from multiple cores and dual CPU workstations. The others are producers of content. All of whom stand to benefit from CUDA and other attributes of Nvidia cards. Yet Apple no longer offers any products with Nvidia integration, or even the possibility of adding Nvidia cards onboard. For all their faults (and there are many), Nvidia still offers far greater professional and gaming performance than AMD. Of all Tim's decisions, the one to not provide any integrated Nvidia options is the most damning of his character and vision of pro users.

Comment: But this decision has a very close, similarly damning, second place: the removal of all options to have a second CPU in any current Pro Mac model, at a time of exponentially increasing demands for power. Content creation is scaling up through massive resolution, colour space and fidelity increases. It shouldn't take a genius to see this trend is increasing. 4K HDR content creation requires as much computing power as possible. Dual CPU configurations have been default base workstations forever and Intel's finally gotten good at making great options. Yet Apple's needlessly stuck on one CPU slot.

Comment: But all of this is preceded by the decision to fire the only real, single threat to Tim's leadership, Scott Forstall, a guy that championed the power and potential of software and developers, for both Apple's coders (and those of the world) via iOS, App Store and the SDKs of iOS and (what is now) MacOS. The quality demise and escalating rate of horribleness that is the Apple documentation and SDKs can be traced right back to the setup and implementation Scott's firing, by Tim, to provide himself with a secure position as the head of Apple, the hardware company, and that which he understands.